# How to fix unstable wireless internet connection with BCM4312?

Tags: wireless

I installed ubuntu 14. I'm having unstable wireless Internet connection with my BCM4312 card. It's connected and after few seconds it's gone.

Please have a look at the [wireless script](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8340993/). What can I do to get a stable connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)

Answer (score 1):

According to your pastebin you need to install the firmware files for your wireless adapter.

```
 [   36.601067] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
 [   36.601073] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
 [   36.601075] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

[Ubuntu has a page dedicated to helping users with broadcom WIFI adapters](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access).

Comment: Thanks !!installed. but still not resolved..wireless script result: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8341228/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the incorrect driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and let us hear your report

Comment: after removing and reboot, no wireless connection is was showing. I had to reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2011191) fixed my issue. The problem was with router security option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (as analyzed in @h0twir3 answer) with the broadcom b43xx firmware.

Simply installing the open source b43 driver ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_driver_.28Open-source.29)) with :

```
 apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

solved my missing firmware problem.